# Silverstripe 3: has_one image in Widget error

Tags: silverstripe

I'm creating a few widgets for a project I'm working on and it seems widgets do not have access to any of the other classes from outside the widget. I've tried adding a has_one static for both image and SiteTree classes (see example below for image example) and I am getting the same error when I try and add the cms field: Fatal error: Call to a member function FormAction() on a non-object in /..../sapphire/forms/FormField.php on line 139

```
<?php
class AdBoxWidget extends Widget{
    static $title = "";
    static $cmsTitle = "Ad Box Widget";
    static $description = "Ad Box widget. To add an image, Title and Link";

    static $db = array(
        "Title" => "Text",
        "Link" => "Text",
        "AdLinkText" => "Text"
    );

    static $defaults = array(
        "Title" => 'Ad Title',
        "Link" => 'http://',        
        "AdLinkText" => 'Click here for more info',
    );

    static $has_one = array(
        'AdImage' => 'Image'
    );

    function getCMSFields(){
        return new FieldList(
            new TextField("Title", "Ad Title"),
            new TextField("Link", "Ad Link"),
            new TextField("AdLinkText", "Text for Link"),
            new UploadField("AdImage", "Ad image")
        );
    }

    function getAd(){
        $output = new ArrayList();
        $output->push(
            new ArrayData(
                array(
                    "Title" => $this->Title,
                    "Link" => $this->Link,
                    "AdLinkText" => $this->AdLinkText
                )
            )
        );
        return $output;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

To prevent a situation like this you could make a DataObject out of one Ad.
Provide a ModelAdmin to edit the Ad DataObjects.

In your widget you could just have a has_one with a DropDownField to select the ad for the widget.

This wont solve the actual problem with the widget module but it works around.